# woocommerce где шаблон изображения товара для хука woocommerce_template_loop_product_thumbnail

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Мне нужно изменить шаблон, обертку (HTML img ) вывода картинки товара.
За вывод картинки отвечает хук 
**woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item** в файле

> /wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/templates/content-product.php

Хук вызывает функцию **woocommerce_get_product_thumbnail**

> wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/includes/wc-template-functions.php

дальше я теряюсь.

Хук оборачивает картинку в

```
<img class="...
```

Вот этот html шаблон в который он оборачивает картинку мне и надо изменить.

**Update**

По мотивам ответа ниже сделал функцию тут my-theme/woocommerce/function.php

```
function filter_woocommerce_product_get_image( $image, $_this, $size, $attr, $placeholder ) {
  if ( has_post_thumbnail( $_this->get_id() ) ) {
            $image = get_the_post_thumbnail( $_this->get_id(), $size, $attr );
    } elseif ( ( $parent_id = wp_get_post_parent_id( $_this->get_id() ) ) && has_post_thumbnail( $parent_id ) ) {
            $image = get_the_post_thumbnail( $parent_id, $size, $attr );
    } elseif ( $placeholder ) {
            $image = custom_wc_placeholder_img( $size );
    } else {
            $image = '';
    }

  return $image;
}

add_filter ( 'woocommerce_product_get_image', 'filter_woocommerce_product_get_image', 10, 5);
```

Вызываю хук в content-product.php

```
do_action( 'woocommerce_product_get_image' );
```

получаю

> Fatal error: Uncaught ArgumentCountError: Too few arguments to
>   function filter_woocommerce_product_get_image()

Comment: Ну так изменяйте.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40767641/how-do-i-return-only-image-src-from-woocommerce-get-product-thumbnail

Comment: Я понимаю что можно изменить функцию на свою и поменять, но мне непонятно как там образуется тег img

Answer (score 3, accepted):

А дальше идет вызов метода get_image() класса WC_Product. Вот код метода:

```
public function get_image( $size = 'shop_thumbnail', $attr = array(), $placeholder = true ) {
    if ( has_post_thumbnail( $this->get_id() ) ) {
        $image = get_the_post_thumbnail( $this->get_id(), $size, $attr );
    } elseif ( ( $parent_id = wp_get_post_parent_id( $this->get_id() ) ) && has_post_thumbnail( $parent_id ) ) {
        $image = get_the_post_thumbnail( $parent_id, $size, $attr );
    } elseif ( $placeholder ) {
        $image = wc_placeholder_img( $size );
    } else {
        $image = '';
    }
    return apply_filters( 'woocommerce_product_get_image', wc_get_relative_url( $image ), $this, $size, $attr, $placeholder );
}
```

Для модификации html кода картинки используйте хук `woocommerce_product_get_image`

Хук должен выглядеть так:

```
function filter_woocommerce_product_get_image( $image, $_this, $size, $attr, $placeholder ) {
    // ваш код модификации $image
    return $image;
}
add_filter ( 'woocommerce_product_get_image', 'filter_woocommerce_product_get_image', 10, 5);
```

Comment: http://woocommerce.wp-a2z.org/oik_api/wc_placeholder_img/ вот именно то, что я искал. Спасибо за наводку.

Comment: а в вопросе ни слова про placeholder ))

Comment: Ну я не знал что он так называется, но в вопросе про тег img который и есть placeholder )

Comment: нет - тег img это тег html img. А placeholder - изображение, которое показывает WooCommerce по умолчанию, если у товара нет своей картинки

Comment: Ок, буду знать. Но где то внутри get_image запрятан тег html img, думаю теперь найду.

Answer (score 2):

Решал подобную задачу, нашел альтернативный вариант - если не можем изменить вывод самой картинки, тогда можем с помощью хуков над ней и под ней обернуть в свой код или div. Написал две функции которые обернут картинку в списке товаров в нужный нам блок с классом:

```html
function img_top_prew()
{echo '<div class="imgcat">';}; 
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item', 'img_top_prew', 10 );
function img_top_bottom()
{echo '</div>';}; 
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item_title', 'img_top_bottom', 10 );
```

Получим обернутую картинку
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]